# Retain count of a synthesized property 

Tags: objective-c, properties, retaincount

Please review my code:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    ClassB *objB;
}

@property (retain) ClassB *objB;
@end

@implementation ClassA:
@synthesiaze objB;
@end

int Main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ClassA *objA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    ClassB *objB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[objB retainCount]);    // 1
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[[objA objB] retainCount]);     // 0

    objA.objB = objB;

    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[objB retainCount]);    // 2
/* --> */    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[[objA objB] retainCount]);     // 3
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[[objA objB] retainCount]);     // 4
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)[objB retainCount]);    // 4
}
```

Please look at line 23,  `NSLog(@"%d", (int)[[objA objB] retainCount]);`

I think the result should be 2 not 3, but every time, calling `[objA objB]` seems to increase the retain count by 1. I don't know what's happening. Who can tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome example of how `retainCount` is uselessly misleading.  It *looks* like the retain count is increased by one, but it is actually a `retain/autorelease`.  Thus, the retain implied by your log message will disappear if you were to [correctly] create and drain an autorelease pool in that example.  I.e. **do not call retainCount**.

Answer (score 4):

Apple has this to say about [`retainCount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCDAAJI):

> **Important:** This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.
>
> To understand the fundamental rules of memory management that you must abide by, read [“Memory Management Rules”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994).

Don't worry about retain counts; just worry about calling `release` if you call `retain`, `alloc`, or a method whose name starts with `copy`, `mutableCopy`, or `new`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't rely on `retainCount` to always be 100% accurate.

That said, what you're seeing is just because the synthesised getter looks like this:

```
- (ClassB *)objB
{
    return [[objB retain] autorelease];
}
```

So, when you ask for the object through a synthesised getter, it is retained and autoreleased. That's because anything you get from a non-ownership getter is supposed to last for the life of the current autorelease pool, but if you released objA in the interim then that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Your @property is not marked as **nonatomic**, so the getter is not just a simple return, but a lock, retain, autorelease and unlock - for thread safety purposes. You can either write your own getter or declare the property as @property (nonatomic, retain)